# Class implementing interfaces with conflicting method signatures

Tags: c#, interface, clr

Let's say we have two interfaces with conflicting method signatures:

```
interface IA
{
    void F();
}

interface IB
{
    int F();
}
```

and now we create a class like this:

```
class Test : IA, IB
{
    public void F() { ... }
    int IB.F() { ... }
}
```

The method named as `IB.F` looks like a `private` method, however you can do something like this:

```
var t = new Test();
t.F();       //Calls public method F
((IB)t).F(); //Calls private method IB.F!!!
```

**So my question is:** how does the C# compiler know that `IB.F` can be called outside the class scope?

I guess it's that `IB.` prefix, but looked into the `IL` code and it just appears as a `private` method with that odd signature.

Comment: Perhaps because all Interface methods are public

Comment: How versed are you in "explicit interface implementation" (which is what this is)? Do some searches around that, if you haven't already.

Comment: @cheedep: Yes you are right, but in the class it is declared as `private` so...

Comment: @user414076: I didn't know about that, but my question is about how the compiler works this out, thanks anyway.

Comment: @e.campver it's not declared as private, try to do so and you'll see what happens. Unlike ordinary methods, interface implementations are public. Doesn't matter whether you declare then as public or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "private" method contains the following:

```
.method private hidebysig newslot virtual final instance int32 ns.IB.F() cil managed
{ 
    .override Tests.IB::F
    //...
}
```

And in `IB`:

```
.method public hidebysig newslot abstract virtual instance int32 F() cil managed
{
}
```

The `.override` tells the compiler to have a look at the declaration in `IB`. There it says that the method is `public`.

The method is not actually declared `private`, "nothing" means `public` for interface methods by default.

Try adding any kind of access modifier in front of `int IB.F()`, it will be a compiler error, because you may not change the accessibility of explicit interface implementations.

Answer (score 2):

A method that looks like

```
int IB.F() { ... }
```

i.e. there is a dot `.` in its name and the part of the name before the (last) dot is an interface name, is not an ordinary instance method. It is a so-called ***explicit interface implementation***.

Do not think of it as a usual `private` method. Note that it is not even legal to use the C# keyword `private` together with an explicit interface implementation.

In a sense, this method has the accessibility of the interface it implements.

So it can be called whenever someone has an instance of that class which is cast to the interface.

As an example, on the MSDN site they do not document `internal` or `private` members of classes. But they *do* document explicit interface implementation (where the interface is visible outside the assembly), because these members can be called from the outside (i.e. by us). See [`List<T>` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) for an example.